# Application compatibility between versions

Tags: android

I can run my application on 1.5, 1.6 and 2.0 emulator and on a 1.5 device without any problems. But some of my users are reporting force close and strange menu entries (see the attachment) using 1.6 and higher version devices. Any ideas?

[alt text http://taypo.com/00.png](http://taypo.com/00.png)

This screen should look like this: http://www.taypo.com/blog/WindowsLiveWriter/TurkceKlavye0.7_6F1/settings_0.7_2.png

And the code that generates this screen is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/general_settings">
                <CheckBoxPreference android:title="@string/haptic_feedback" android:defaultValue="true"
                        android:summary="@string/haptic_feedback_summary" android:key="vibrate" />
                <CheckBoxPreference android:title="@string/sound_feedback" android:defaultValue="false"
                        android:summary="@string/sound_feedback_summary" android:key="sound" />
                <CheckBoxPreference android:title="@string/auto_caps" android:defaultValue="true"
                        android:summary="@string/auto_caps_summary" android:key="auto_caps" />
        </PreferenceCategory>
        <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/layout_settings">
                <ListPreference android:title="@string/keyboard_layout" android:defaultValue="TRQ"
                        android:key="kbd_layout" android:entries="@array/layout_names" android:entryValues="@array/layout_values" />
        </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Could you give another screenshot of how the screen is supposed to look?  Also, could you give the code/layout that generates the screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are references to entries in your strings.xml file.  That should not have changed between versions.  Are you using any localization for your resources?  Lets say you have a values-en, and values-es, but you don't have a values then your app will support English and Spanish but if someone has their locale set to German you will get something that looks like this.

Comment: That is exactly what I was doing. And I am finally able to reproduce the problem on the emulator. Thank you. I will release an update and get some more feedback.